# Named pipe (mkfifo) output format

Tags: c++, string-formatting, named-pipes

I am using a named pipe so a reader and a writer can communicate. The text I am moving is from an array of strings text[lines] and every lines consists of 4 words (or numbers) separated by a space.
The reader is:

```
string temptext1[lines];

int bufs = 1024;
char tempchar1[bufs];
for (int l = 0; l < lines; l++)
{
ssize_t chars1 = read(rfd1, tempchar1, bufs);
if (chars1 > 0)
    temptext1[l].assign(tempchar1, chars1);
tempchar1[0] = '\0';
}
```

And the writer:

```
wfd = open(fifoname.c_str(), O_WRONLY);
for (int p = 0; p < lines; p++)
{
    write(wfd, text[p].c_str(), text[p].length());
}
close(wfd);
```

However, the output of the writer is not always the same. Sometimes it omits changing line and so the outpus comes in blocks. Some are as they were supposed and others change line only if the buffer size is reached. Example:

```
1197332 Hunter Steven 62926191228732 Watkins Wanda 49260191248845 Raynor Martha 65254191251116 Chang Maurice 47853191265074 Cunningham Wesley 30632191273625 Vaughn Alicia 66399191277060 Doyle Kate 48450191289231 Patrick Eva 17533191291543 Hinson Sylvia 46649191311074 Fink Theodore 50564191321632 Stark Grace 64052191343213 Cooper Kristen 69265191357025 Bernstein Scott 22360191371284 Wall Erica 26280191372274 Knox Jill 44535191402568 Cox Claudia 27013191415579 Duke Gayle 39376191427406 Stein Evan 56028191442007 Barker Justin 15260191442433 Gross Robert 23075
191456852 McCall Nelson 3580
191471786 Lassiter Steven 13812
191475523 Hayes Warren 38732
191478103 Spencer Christine 46819
191516369 Skinner Lisa 51427
191522499 O'Connor Nicholas 66851
```

If i print the contents of the array in a file:

```
ofstream outofs("Taksinomimena3.txt", ios::app);
if (!outofs.is_open())
    return 1;
for (int p = 0; p < lines; p++)
    outofs << text[p] << "\n";
outofs.close();
```

everything is printed as it is supposed.

Comment: There's no guarantee a pipe is flushed when you write EOL to it. So your read() may no give you the full string on each call!